# Show that the MLE of $\theta$ is $\hat \theta = X_2$

Tags: inference, point-estimation

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid $exp(\theta)$ random variables.

If we observe only $X_2$, Show that the MLE of $\theta$ is  $\hat\theta  = X_2$

I've tried to write the joint of $X_1$, $X_2$ and did the likelihood maximization but couldn't get $X_2$ but instead, I was getting a formula with $X_1$ in it.

Does anyone know how to go about the first step?
For some reasons, I'm lost with the first step which is writing the likelihood function

Comment: If you only observe $X_1$ then presumably the sampling distribution would be $p(x_1|\theta)$ and so the likelihood function would not involve $X_2$.

Comment: The answer to *any* question that concerns only $X_2$ cannot involve $X_1!$  Thus, it's pointless to write down a joint distribution.  The *only* thing that matters is the distribution of $X_2.$

Comment: Perfect. I was a bit thrown off by as why I would be asked that.  Thank you !